# How can i sort date in dictionnary?

Tags: swift, date, dictionary

i try to sort the dictionnary by dates after grouping the orders coming from backkend by dates  but the dates of the orders not arranged still appear randomly i try different way  i convert the date strings to Dates, then sort by date and i tried to sort the date string but stay the same problem

> 

this is my code when i try to convert the  date strings coming from server to dates`:

```
func personsByMonth(persons : [Orderproperties])  {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        df.dateStyle = .short
        let dictionaryByMonth = Dictionary(grouping: persons, by: { getDatebyString(date: $0.dateCreated ?? "") })
            .sorted{guard let d1 = df.date(from:$0.key) , let d2 = df.date(from:$1.key) else {return false}
           return d1 < d2}
        print(dictionaryByMonth)

    
        for (key, orders) in dictionaryByMonth{
            var item = [OrderItems]()
        
            for order in  orders {
                if (order.status == "completed") {
                item.append(OrderItems(image: "delivered", location: order.billing?.city ?? "", quantity: String(order.lineItems.count), state: order.status ?? "", price: order.total ?? "0"))
                }
                else {
                    item.append(OrderItems(image: "inprogress", location: order.billing?.city ?? "", quantity: String(order.lineItems.count), state: order.status ?? "", price: order.total ?? "0"))
                }
            }
            ordersValue.append(OrderWithHeaders(headers: key , orderItems: item))
        }
    
    }
    
    func getDatebyString(date :String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)!
        return date.formatted(.dateTime.year().month().day())
    }
```

this is my Model

```
struct Orderproperties: Codable  , Identifiable{
    let id, parent_id: Int?
    let status: String?
    let currency: String?
    let version: String?
    let pricesIncludeTax: Bool
    let discountTotal, discountTax: String?
    let datePaid, datePaidGmt, dateCompleted,dateCompletedGmt : String?
    let dateCreated , dateCreatedGmt , dateModified , dateModifiedGmt: String?
    let shippingTotal, shippingTax, cartTax, total: String?
    let totalTax: String?
    let customerID: Int?
    let order_key: String? }
```

but the dates of the orders not arranged still appear randomly

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you can sort a dictionary. The result is an array of the dictionary's elements which are tuples of the keys and associated values.

Comment: If you want to sort persons as array then its easy to do that.. 
you didn't write you model Orderproperties here ... ]

Comment: I saw you in Facebook group

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII  yeah that's me because i didn't found the solution

Comment: @JeremyP how can i fix my problem because i try to sort the dictionnary

Comment: you didn't provide full code here we have to vote you negative if you still didn't provide full model info like OrderItems, OrderWithHeaders and al

Comment: you just to sort Orderproperties ? why you converting into dictionary ?

Comment: orderitems or orderHeaders don't have any relation with sorting dates

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII because i want the orders coming from the server frouping by the same dates that's why i used the dictionary

Comment: your approach is bad. you just have to make thing clear first. contact over fb in detail so I can help

Comment: ordersValue.sort(by: { $0.headers < $1.headers })

Comment: thank you all i solved my problem with this                                             
           `var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MM, yyyy"// yyyy-MM-dd"
        
        let dictionaryByMonth = Dictionary(grouping: persons, by: { getDatebyString(date: $0.dateCreated ?? "") })
        var ready2 = dictionaryByMonth.sorted(by: { dateFormatter.date(from:$0.key)?.compare(dateFormatter.date(from:$1.key) ?? Date()) == .orderedDescending })
        print(ready2)`

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a dictionary is not really possible. This is because of the data structure that it has. It has no indices but it uses a hash of the key to access the value in memory.

You can call .sorted(by: >) on a dictionary but it returns an array of tuples with the key and value. So if you sort it directly on the for loop it should work.

```
for (key, value) in dictionary.sorted(by: >) { ... }
```